# How do I read from a file and print to the console without using a variable using C++?

Tags: c++

In my code I have

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ranInts= rand();//generate a random integer, store in ranInts
    cout << ranInts<< " ";//Print out ints
    binaryFile.write(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&ranInts), sizeof(int))//Write to file
        }
```

The code to read is

```
binaryFile.seekg(ios::beg);//Set the pointer in file to beginning
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    binaryFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&ranInts), sizeof(int));
    //reading each int moves the file pointer down 4 bytes, ready to get the next one

    //display
    cout << ranInts<< endl;
}
```

This works fine. What I want to do is go from the disk to the screen and leave the variable out of the loop.

Is this possible?

Comment: I never used C++ but I imaging it would be sth like this? binaryFile.write(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&rand()), sizeof(int))//Write to file
        }

Comment: @JohnP. You can't take the address of a temporary, which is what the return value of `rand()` is. It needs to be stored in a variable so that the `write` function can access it by pointer. @Michael I do not quite understand what you are asking. You simply want to output the contents of a file in the console, or something different?

Comment: Youir code writes to a file. How does that correlate to *read from a file and print to the console*? Where's your code to *read from a file and print to the console using a variable* first?

Comment: the code basically does the reverse. It reads the file and stores it in the same variable, then prints it to the screen so... I want to write to the disk then read and display from the disk without the variable...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Call `std::copy` to copy an `std::istream_iterator` based on your file into an `std::ostream_iterator` based on `cout`:

```
std::ifstream file("myinput.txt");  // Open your input file
file.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws); // Make sure whitespace is not skipped
std::copy(                          // Call std:copy to copy the content
    std::istream_iterator<char>(file)
,   std::istream_iterator<char>()
,   std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "")
);
```

Comment: I'm doing my research here but from what I can see I have to deal with a couple of things.

1. how does it know how long each character is?
2. it looks like its reading the whole file?
3. What line actually prints the single line from my file?

To give more information this data is being stored in a binary file so as you can see I am pulling the data out in size int.

Preferably I would like to not have to use
    
     #include <sstream>
     #include <iterator>
     #include <numeric>

To make this work...

Comment: @Michael This code does read the entire file. Each character is the size of `char`, the template type parameter of stream iterators. If you are reading a binary file, parameterize your streams on `int` instead of `char`, and use some non-empty separator instead of `""` on the last line. Nothing prints a single line - the copying is done one `char` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go from disk to the screen (two different devices ) its really not a problem.

1. open the disk for reading the file
2. test for the end of file indicator.
   code:
   z = open( the file on the disk )  // returns a ID
   for (,,){ // this is a forever loop it could be written as: 
   FOREVER {
   if you #define FOREVER   for(;;)     this should go in you header file.
   or you could use do{....}while ( z > 0 );
   read( from z , buffer)
   you should test the buffer to make sure your buffer is not empty or did you reach the end of the file.
   fprintf( print the buffer contents )

note with this strategy you must know the lenth of the buffer.
char buffer[50] make shure you add one for the eol char \n"

have fun.